# Don't understand why this is a contradiction

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

[image]

I was going through the above proof but don't understand the part where it claims that $X_{i_{n}} = \emptyset$ is a contradiction to the assumption that the infinite intersection is the empty set.

Comment: It's a contradiction to the definition of the $X_n$ as closures of nonempty sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$X_{i_n}=\overline{\{x_k:k\geq i_n\}}$$

At the very least $X_{i_n}$ has one element, namely $x_{i_n}.$ Hence, it can't be empty so you have a contradiction.

Comment: Makes sense! I was looking at the wrong contradiction! Thanks!

Comment: Usually in a proof wouldnt the statement that follows 'Suppose for contradiction' be the statement that gets contradicted?

Comment: @Duke, No not necessarily. You could assume that suppose $A$ is true and arrive at $1<0.$ Even that is a contradiction. The point is to start by assuming something holds, and if you arrive at anything which you know for a 'fact' is not true, then you arrive at a contradiction. Because you have shown that if $A \implies (\text{ 'fact' doesn't hold })$ which is absurd.

Comment: Ah yes that makes complete sense, but in this proof how are we able to assume the fact that $U_n$ forms an open cover. EDIT: I understand my confusion now, thank you for your help!!

Comment: **Hint:** DeMorgan's law.